# (Undefined index: driver) Why I am obtaining this error message when I try to perform a database query on a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am pretty new in **Laravel** and I have the following doubt about how to correctly configure the database connection.

I am using **Laravel 5.4** and I need to connect to an existing **MySql** database. So following this tutorial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database

I have setted my **config/database.php** file in this way:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    //'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        /*
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
        */

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'pandaok'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        /*
        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
        */

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    /*
    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],
    */

];
```

As you can see in the previous code snippet I comment all except the settings related to **MySql**.

I commented also this line:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

to avoid that it takes the connection parameter from the **.env** files that contains:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

But doing in this way I am obtaining this error message when I perform this query into a class **$resut = DB::select('select * from pm_user where id = ?', [1]);**:

```
ErrorException in DatabaseManager.php line 112:
Undefined index: driver
in DatabaseManager.php line 112
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined index: driver', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\HotelRegistration\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager.php', 112, array('name' => null, 'config' => array('mysql' => array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '3306', 'database' => 'homestead', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => true, 'engine' => null)))) in DatabaseManager.php line 112
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection(null) in DatabaseManager.php line 71
at DatabaseManager->connection() in DatabaseManager.php line 322
at DatabaseManager->__call('select', array('select * from pm_user where id = ?', array(1))) in Facade.php line 221
at DatabaseManager->select('select * from pm_user where id = ?', array(1)) in Facade.php line 221
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

And why Laravel defines the database connection parameters in 2 different places (the **config/database.php** file and the **.env** file)?

Comment: Did one of the below answers solve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to uncomment this line:

`'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`

Laravel does not define it in 2 different places. If you refer the env function signature, the second param is the default value when there is no variable named `DB_CONNECTION` defined in the .env file

If this still doesn't work try `php artisan config:clear` followed by `php artisan config:cache`. Post the errors if you need any further help

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting here:

> HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined index: driver',...

is because you've commented out `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`.

If you don't want the `.env` file to dictate what connection is used then just don't use the `env()` helper function i.e.

```
'default' => 'mysql'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few levels to this you should be aware of. As you're likely aware database credentials should never be committed into your code repository so a natural place to place them is environment variables.

For this reason, it is best to avoid placing them in **config/database.php** directly.

During local development they should be placed in your .env file as you mentioned. However, if they're not updating and you're getting this error it's likely you have just cached an incorrect config file, you can clear this by doing:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Although you may also need to remove the commented-out code here:

```
//'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

However, one feature that the laravel documentation glances over is that .env files should not be used in production. Laravel uses a package called phpdotenv:

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

> phpdotenv is made for development environments, and generally should not be used in production.

A workaround to this is to keep using .env to store your variables, but make sure they're all referenced in the **config/database.php** in your laravel config files and run this command so that laravel does not rely on the .env file in production

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: It wasn't my question, Ross ;)

Comment: Haha, sorry about that.